# How to retrieve output parameter from stored procedure using Entity Framework 6

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, entity-framework

Stored procedure:

```
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

CREATE PROCEDURE spInsertData
    @UNAME varchar(20),
    @Pass varchar(20),
    @Active bit,
    @City nvarchar(20),
    @Phone nvarchar(10)
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    -- Insert statements for procedure here
    INSERT INTO Login 
    VALUES(@UNAME, @Pass, @Active, @City, @Phone) 

    SELECT SCOPE_IDENTITY() AS Id
END
GO
```

C# code-behind:

```
namespace AjaxJqueryDemo
{
    public partial class Reg : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        TraineeEntities DB = new TraineeEntities();

        protected void btnReg_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
           int i = DB.spInsertData(uname.Text, Pass.Text,true, city.Text, pHno.Text);
        }
    }
}
```

How to fetch the scope identity so that I can ensure data is inserted?

I am not using gridview and neither am I interested in using it. How can I 
fetch it simply?

Please give answers with more detailed explanation so that I can understand..

Comment: If you had an entity `User` (or `Trainee` or whatever) and would be using **Entity Framework** to actually insert it, you would have this feature (getting back the newly inserted `Id`) automatically and **for free** - no effort on your part needed. Do you **really** need to use that stored procedure? ***Really?!?!?!***

Comment: Assuming that for some (political?) reason you must use a stored proc (which as marc_s points out is not unnecessary), why are you `SELECT`ing instead of `RETURN`ing? Chances are your ID is an `INT` so you don't need all the overhead of a data set being returned. If, again for some unknown reason, you *must* `SELECT` it, then treat it in the same way you return any other data - as a set of columns and rows.

Comment: Please give me solution for this, i am new to Store Procedure, if possible then implement in my code so that i can understand easily. 
Thanks in advance,

Comment: Typo alert: it's a **stored** procedure - as in **stored** inside of SQL Server - it has nothing to do with a "store" .... and since that stored procedure is neither Holy, nor Royal, nor denotes a geographical place, there's absolutely no need to capitalize the leading letters, either....

Comment: Instead of giving any solution you guys are just giving useless suggestions, i repeat that i am new this and couldn't find solution by Searching on Google...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please check bellow code it will give you better suggestion.

```
ALTER PROCEDURE dbo.YourProcedure
@params VARCHAR(32),
@Table1ID INT = NULL OUTPUT
AS
BEGIN
  SET NOCOUNT ON;

  BEGIN TRANSACTION;

  INSERT dbo.Table1...
  SET @Table1ID = SCOPE_IDENTITY();
  INSERT dbo.Table2...

  COMMIT TRANSACTION;
END
GO
```